# How to save number of times a user has tapped on a view

Tags: android, file, local-storage

I am designing a simple application that will count how many times a user has tapped on a imageView. My question is what would be the best way of saving and reading this file. Any suggestions? I am thinking something like using Parse.com's local database. I have tried it, but I could not get it working the way I wanted. I am still a beginner, so please not so fancy suggestions.

Comment: I am not sure what exactly that is, but I suspect access by other apps to this file. If that is the case, I wont mind to be public.

Comment: it is only accessible by your app. Read the documentation

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest options is always thebest option, go with [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Here is simple tutorial from google http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

It will store your data in application local file. Take a note of that there are different shared preferences in example getPreferences() will return file specific for activity you used this method. While getSharedPreferences() will return application global file.

Comment: Thanks! It looks like I am going to use this. It seems fairly easy to implement. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

Try to save data in SharedPreference. SharedPreference works like database for application on device that will be stored until any one has unistall app from device.

To create sharedPrefernce-

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
      "com.example.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

To store data -

```
prefs.edit().putInt("key", int_value).apply();
```

To retrieve data-

```
// use a default value 
int l = prefs.getLong("key", default_value);
```